# Set ComboBoxUI for all JComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, uimanager

Hi I want to change look for all ComboBoxes in my app.

MyComboBox class:

```
class MyComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {


    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new MyComboBoxUI();
    }

    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.EAST);
        return button;
    }
}
```

And i call it like this:

```
UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", "MyComboBoxUI");
```

It produces this error:

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: javax.swing.JComboBox
```

When i use:

```
someComboBox.setUI((ComboBoxUI) MyComboBoxUI.createUI(someComboBox));
```

It works like a charm

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified class name of MyComboBoxUI when setting it to the UIManager

Comment: I dont know exactly how to do it. I treid: `put("ComboBoxUI", "com.zad2.okna.MyComboBoxUI")` and it didnt work

Comment: The fully qualified name of the class is the package + class name

Comment: `com.zad2.okna.MyComboBoxUI` is package + class name.

Comment: Ok i was able to make it work. My mistake was creating class MyComboBoxUI inside the same file where i was calling it by `UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", "MyComboBoxUI");`. When i have moved it to different file it started to work with fully qualified class name.

Comment: Right, try using UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", "com.zad2.okna.MyComboBoxUI");

Comment: 1. right is only about the fully qualified name of the class ..., by assuming that MyComboBoxUI isn't compiled in separate jar, 2. please whats someComboBox.setUI((ComboBoxUI) MyComboBoxUI.createUI(someComboBox));